# Blender 2.8 - Why does the Waves Surface Type not have an output panel?

Tags: shaders, dynamic-paint

We need the wave data generated on a Dynamic Paint canvas as a data layer in Blender 2.8, but realized that there is no [Output](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/canvas.html#output) panel available when [Waves](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/canvas.html#waves) is selected as the Dynamic Paint Surface Type. Is there an other way to get that data into an Attribute node in the Shader Editor?